# Espresso: How to verify list is alphabetically sorted?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am able to verify items in the list by their alignment using following methods
isBottomAlignedWith
isTopAlignedWith
isLeftAlignedWith
isRightAlignedWith

How can we verify sorting order in the list? Please give me an example.

Comment: can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

1. Iterate over the items
2. insert the text into a new list
3. clone the list
4. sort the cloned list
5. compare it to the list from 2